# Можно ли сделать цикл быстрее?

Tags: python, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Я хочу рассчитать попарные расстояния между точками набора. pdist мне не подходит, т.к. на некоторые расстояния, не удовлетворяющие условию, я хочу наложить "штраф" в виде множителя. В среднем для набора цикл длится минуты 3-4, наборов около 900 - время получается неприемлемым. Может быть можно этот цикл организовать по-другому?

```
distances = np.zeros((lat_long.values.shape[0], lat_long.values.shape[0]))
for i in range(lat_long.values.shape[0]):
    for j in range(lat_long.values.shape[0]):
        if i < j:
            if user_data.loc[i,'day_night_label'] == user_data.loc[j,'day_night_label']:
                    distance = cdist(lat_long.values[i:i+1], lat_long.values[j:j+1], metric=dist)
            else:
                    distance = 15*cdist(lat_long.values[i:i+1], lat_long.values[j:j+1], metric=dist)
            distances[i,j] = distance
        else:
            distances[i,j] = 0
distances += distances.T
```

Comment: А вы используйте `pdist`. А штраф наложите позже.

Comment: Используя pdist я получу матрицу расстояний, затем в этой матрице некоторые элементы нужно будет увеличить в k раз. Это ведь все равно придется делать циклом, так в чем разница?

Comment: Матрицу штрафов можно сделать групповыми операциями. В конце умножите две матрицы поэлементно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Да, это должно помочь. Только вот в чем еще вопрос. У меня есть датафрейм, некоторые строки которого (примерно половина) имеют метку 1, остальные - метку 0. Штраф я хочу наложить в тех случаях, когда вычисляется расстояние между строками с разными метками. Как сформировать матрицу штрафов групповыми операциями?

Comment: Залейте матрицу штрафом. Выделите индексы для метки ноль в виде массива индексов `indices0`, по этим индексам залейте единицу: `m[indices0, indices0] = 1`. То же сделайте для единиц.

Comment: Кажется понял. Большое спасибо, будем пробовать)

Comment: Как задана переменная `dist`?

Answer (score 1):

Если изменить порядок операций то можно добиться ускорения примерно в 500-1000 раз.

Комбинация `squareform(pdist(...))` вычисляет попарные расстояния в виде квадратной матрицы.

`factor` - матрица коэффициентов (штрафов). Первоначально она вся заполнена штрафами. Затем все ячейки с одинаковыми значениями столбца `day_night_label` заполняются единицами.

В конце штрафы умножаются на расстояния:

```
distances = squareform(pdist(lat_long.values, metric=dist))
factor = np.full((lat_long.values.shape[0], lat_long.values.shape[0]), 15)
for v in user_data['day_night_label'].unique():
    index = (user_data['day_night_label'] == v).values
    factor[np.ix_(index, index)] = 1
distances *= factor
```

Предыдущий способ можно улучшить ещё примерно в полтора раза. Тут `factor` вычисляется через выражение `pdist(ud, metric='hamming')` которое вычисляет единицу если пара значений в user_data['day_night_label'] различны, ноль иначе. Матрица штрафов (она пока не матрица) тоже вычисляется через `pdist`!

```
distances = pdist(lat_long.values, metric=dist)
ud = user_data['day_night_label'].values.reshape(
    (user_data['day_night_label'].shape[0], 1)
)
factor = 1 + 14 * pdist(ud, metric='hamming')
distances = squareform(distances * factor)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Dist - это функция, вычисляющая расстояние между точками, заданными широтой-долготой. Ваш способ с заливкой матрицы штрафов помог, спасибо. Возник еще 1 вопрос. При вычислении попарных расстояний `distances = squareform(pdist(lat_long.values, metric=dist))` как можно обойти проблему с большим количеством данных? В частности при 30000 строк данных в lat_long, время вычисления парных расстояний огромно.

Comment: **1.** 30000 точек -> 450 миллионов пар. Подумайте нужны ли вам все пары? **2.** dist может вычислятся сложно (тригонометрия, например). Вам нужны точные расстояния? Если, нет, то от угловых координат можно перейти к пространственным и вычислять расстояние как евклидово, что намного быстрее. И есть ещё хитрости в запасе.